# How to install RGui to update R version

Tags: r

This may be an odd question: where do I find RGui?

I want to update my R-version from 4.1.2 to 4.2. I found this [website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-upgrade-r-installation-to-r-4-0-on-windows/) which uses RGui. However I cannot find a RGui in my Windows Start Menu and searching the web yields [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/rgui/).

I believe I have to install any RGui and run the installation commands, is this correct? If so, can you recommend a software?

Comment: If i remember correctly, by default R and programs will be installed to directory  C:\Program Files\R, so programs will be there unless you have explicitly requested it be installed elsewhere. Have a look in those directories for Rgui.exe -- then perhaps add a shortcut on your desktop. Nowadays, here are other options: see the *IDEs and editors for R* section at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info

Comment: I've used pretty much the procedure in your link "website", and that worked fine. You shouldn't need the source forge site. I also have just gone to [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/) and downloaded the installer, ran it, then restarted RStudio, and that works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Rgui comes with R.  There is nothing extra to install to run it.  You do not need RStudio in order to run Rgui.  RStudio is a front end to R that is separate from Rgui and is an alternative to Rgui .  Unlike Rgui, RStudio does not come with R.

To get a desktop icon, run the R installer again and make sure you have the item checked for a Desktop Icon.

To locate Rgui.exe try this from the Windows cmd line assuming R is installed in the standard location.

```
cd C:\Program Files\R
dir /b /s Rgui.exe
```

Also if Rgui is already on your path then running this from the Windows cmd line should find it.

```
where Rgui.exe
```